# Installing tarball when you already have a package (different versions)

Tags: installation, package-management

I want to install Cython so I installed the current package in the software center which is version 0.13, Now I want to install the tarball from the Cython website - version 0.15.

If I just "./configure,make,make install" the tarball, will it work well with the package?
i.e will I be able to later remove it with "apt-get", or will it cause conflicts?

Otherwise I can remove the package first and than install the tarball, but it
won't be as convenient as having the package installed.

What is the best practice in a case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing from source in that way does not involve the use of Ubuntu's package manager. Also, default behavior of all most all applications' source distributions (tarballs) is to install in `/usr/local` rather than `/usr` (where software is installed by the package manager). Therefore, you don't have to remove the version already installed through the package manager, though it may be helpful to do so (it will make sure the version you want is always the version that gets run and will decrease the likelihood that different versions will use each other's libraries and throw subtle and bizarre errors), and is unlikely to hurt.

Software installed from source in the way you've described certainly will not be updated by `apt-get`.

To uninstall the version installed from a source tarball in the way you've described, you can usually run `sudo make uninstall`. You must be in the same directory you were in when you ran `sudo make install`.